# Finding the integral from 0 to 4 using right end point

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I have a question asking me to find the (integral from 0 to 4) $$(3x^2)*dx$$
I found delta x to be $\frac{4}{n}$ and x sub i to be $\frac{4i}{n}$ and f(x sub i)= $3(\frac{4i}{n})^2$ or $3\frac{-16}{n^2}= \frac{-48}{n^2}$,
$lim(n->inf)$ summation i=1 to n = $\frac{-48}{n^2}*\frac{4}{n}$$$$$the answer I get from that however, with n approaching 0 and in the denominator is just zero, which isn't right. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: See the definition here : http://www.sosmath.com/CBB/viewtopic.php?t=59188

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n3\left(\dfrac{4i}n\right)^2=\dfrac{48}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^ni^2=\dfrac{48}{n^2}\cdot\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6$$

Comment: Off of that I'm just getting infinity...?

Comment: @windy401, $$\dfrac 4n\cdot\dfrac{48}{n^2}\cdot\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6=32(1+1/n)(2+1/n)=?$$

Comment: I'm having trouble going from that first part to the second and I'm not having much luck going from there........ I don't think I have a good enough algebra foundation to be in calculus............